# Undefined Reference to Symbol '<Symbol>' ... Error Adding Symbols: DSO Missing From Command Line (With CMake)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Quick overview of the problem:

I am writing a project and was able to get the code I had written (so far) to compile, so I thought to myself I should start writing an example executable to make sure everything is working as I intended. I am a novice at C++ and even more of a novice at CMake (so forgive me if the code doesn't look well). After creating the ground work for the executable file I decided to `make` it and I ended up getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/oneLinkAdaptive.dir/oneLinkAdaptiveExample.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5robot12configurator16initializeParamsEPKc'
/usr/bin/ld: //home/pi/Desktop/cfucr/build/src/configurator/libconfigurator-libs.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/examples/CMakeFiles/oneLinkAdaptive.dir/build.make:86: src/examples/oneLinkAdaptive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:46987: src/examples/CMakeFiles/oneLinkAdaptive.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

From my understanding this is actually a CMake error and that I'm either failing to add a library or maybe I am failing to find a function in my C++ code I wrote(?):

```
namespace robot
{
namespace configurator
{

std::tuple<ParamsR, ParamsF, ParamsC> initializeParams(const char* configFile);
...
```

(I am less inclined to believe the C++ code is what's wrong, but honestly I have no idea at this point.) I have done some snooping around online and tried some things from other posts, i.e., moving the library around to make sure the `libsconfigurator-libs` library was being creating before adding the executable to CMake, checking to make sure I was actually including the `libsconfigurator-libs` library, changing things from `PRIVATE` to `PUBLIC`, etc.

The main `src` CMake file is written as:

```
# Add controller main files #
add_library(cfucr-libs
  controller.cpp
  controller.hpp
)

# Add the `src` directory to be included #
set(CFUCR_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

include_directories(
  ${CFUCR_BASE_DIR}
)

# Add a list of subdirectories #
add_subdirectory(configurator)
add_subdirectory(control)
add_subdirectory(filter)
add_subdirectory(mathUtilities)
add_subdirectory(thirdParty)
add_subdirectory(types)

target_link_libraries(cfucr-libs PRIVATE
  configurator-libs
  control-libs
  filter-libs
  math-utilities-libs
  type-libs
  tinyxml2
  eigen
)

add_subdirectory(examples)
```

The executable file is located down in the `examples` sub-directory, so I moved that `add_subdirectory` to the bottom of the file. That way, I could make sure to add all of the other libraries I created to the main `cfucr` library. The `examples` CMake file is written as:

```
# Add controller example main files #
add_library(examples-libs
  oneLinkAdaptiveExample.cpp
)

# Make executable files for controller examples #
add_executable(oneLinkAdaptive
  oneLinkAdaptiveExample.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(oneLinkAdaptive PRIVATE
  cfucr-libs
  examples-libs
)
```

Basically, to just create the executable and add the main library to it. The configurator library is super simple and is given as:

```
# Add configurator files #
add_library(configurator-libs
  configurator.cpp
  configurator.hpp
)
```

I have been trying to fix this for a bit now but nothing seems to work/I don't fully understand how all of this works to really be able to fix the problem on my own. If anyone has any ideas on what I might be doing incorrectly I would love to hear it. Also, if I need to post anything else (any more CMake files or source files) to help make things clearer let me know and I will post them!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try changing this call to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(cfucr-libs PRIVATE
  configurator-libs
  control-libs
  filter-libs
  math-utilities-libs
  type-libs
  tinyxml2
  eigen
)
```

to use `PUBLIC` instead:

```
target_link_libraries(cfucr-libs PUBLIC
  configurator-libs
  control-libs
  filter-libs
  math-utilities-libs
  type-libs
  tinyxml2
  eigen
)
```

With `PRIVATE`, the listed libraries (e.g. `configurator-libs`) are not made part of the link interface. So, consuming CMake targets (e.g. your executable) will not have visibility of these libraries and their definitions. With `PUBLIC`, the listed libraries *are* added to the link interface, so your executable `oneLinkAdaptive` consumes them also when you link `cfucr-libs` to it.

I encourage you to read through the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents) documentation, particularly the linked section describing the differences between the scoping keywords (i.e. `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE`, etc).

Comment: Updated to do have `PUBLIC` inside of the library! I had tried that before, but when I did that I got a bunch of undefined references, so I thought I was making things worse. Thanks for the clarity! I will try to see if I can fix those undefined references!